# Clarification regarding gmtoff

Tags: sas

I have two line below

```
 %let dl="06jul2016"
 date=dhms("&dl",d,00,00,00);
 date1=dhms("&dl",d,00,00,00)-gmtoff();
 date2=dhms("&dl",d,24,00,00)-gmtoff();
```

Output

```
date=2016-07-06T00:00:00
date1=2016-07-06T04:00:00
date2=2016-07-06T04:00:00
```

Could anyone explain me the result.

Thannkyou

Comment: How does the output differ from what you were expecting?

Comment: Your code shouldn't work as is, so I suspect you have something else going on. You're missing the `d` to specify a date literal, you have an extra comma before the d?

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to reproduce your output. After tidying up your code, I got some slightly different output:

Code:

```
%let dl="06jul2016"d;
data _null_;
date=dhms(&dl,00,00,00);
date1=dhms(&dl,00,00,00)-gmtoff();
date2=dhms(&dl,24,00,00)-gmtoff();
format  date: is8601dt.;
put (_all_) (=/);
run;
```

Output:

```
 date=2016-07-06T00:00:00
 date1=2016-07-06T00:00:00
 date2=2016-07-07T00:00:00
```

Is that closer to what you were expecting?

Answer (score 0):

`gmtoff()` is a correction function for Greenwich Mean Time. So depending on your computers timezone, the results will differ. The input time is GMT and depending on your local timezone  x hours are added/substracted. As you are using`-gmtoff()` you are subtracting the correction factor. That may produce unwanted results.

Also date1 & date2 should produce a difference of one day. Something seems off with your output.